# firefox automatically triggers javascript function named 'onload'

Tags: javascript, firefox

Can someone confirm that firefox (3.6) automatically runs the javascript function named 'onload' without explicitly being called? Chrome and IE do not automatically run a declared function unless called, but firefox apparently will run the declared function 'onload' even if it is not called (all in lowercases).

Here is the jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/XF78b/4/) to test.

In the body tag, if you assign the function named 'test' to onload event, then firefox will call the test function.  If you remove the onload call, firefox will call the function 'onload' automatically.

Is this a known property of firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox 3.6 does in fact do that.  So do 4-8.  Firefox 9 fixes this bug, so that `function onload() {}` no longer adds the function as a load event listener.  See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=659350 for the details of that change.

Comment: Thanks Boris, I was surprised that Tomas claimed that he was unable to duplicate the behavior using FF.

Answer (score 3):

It's because if you declare a global `function onload()`, it's in fact `window.onload`.
This example explains it:

```
<script>
var a = 1;
alert(window.a); // alerts "1"
</script>
```

This should be cross-browser valid (I tested it only on FF3.6 and IE7,8 though).

Comment: Wouldn't that then fire in every browser, not just Firefox?

Comment: My original question is same as Clive, I just updated the link, if you use IE or chrome, and you delete the onload function call in the body tag, IE and chrome don't fire.

Comment: Your explanation is correct, but global function and method of `window` object are not always the same. Good example is the `window.name` property: `window.name = "foo"` causes that links with `target=foo` will open in that window, but when using `name = "foo"` or `var name = "foo"`, the results are different in every browser. The `onload`/`window.onload` issue is very similar to it.

Comment: @Clive, I'd expect it to be cross browser valid, in contraty to Jamex's information I tested it in IE with the same result as in FF.

Comment: @Tomas you're not quite right for properties that actually live on the prototype and have getters/setters (which is how the spec says `onload` should work).  `var` and `function` define own data properties on the window itself, so they can shadow prototype properties.